# Leaflet geoJson and Mysql, how to optimize an extremely slow query

Tags: mysql, leaflet, geojson

I need to create a geoJson polygon layer, the data is in a mysql db and it refers to regions of a country. Specifically I need to count the number of objects in each region. My map shows the regions colored according to the number of artifacts found, sort of like a coropleth.
The objects are in a table with foreign key to the regions table.
The web application and the db are on different servers and this definitely worsens the performance

I tried a query like this:

```
select c.name, st_asgeojson(c.geom) geometry, count(a.*) tot 
from county c 
inner join artifact a on a.county = c.id 
group by c.name
```

The query gave me an error because I did not enter geometry in the group by, but if I group by geometry as well the db goes "out of memory".
I rewrote the query using the "with" construct:

```
with 
  props AS (select county, count(*) tot from artifact group by county), 
  geom as (select id, name, st_asgeojson(geom) geometry from county) 
select geom.id, geom.name, geom.geometry, props.tot 
from props 
inner join geom on props.county = geom.id;
```

it works but it is extremely slow, almost 10 seconds for about ten polygons...I tried explain analyze but there seems to be no problem, also because all field are indexed:

[image: analyze and explain results]

I've always used Postgresql, which I find much more robust when working with geographic data, in this case however I have to use Mysql, so I'm asking if there is a smarter way to optimize the query to get a collection of geoJson to be managed with Leaflet

Comment: `count(a.*)` does not make sense.  Please explain in English.

Comment: @RickJames, why does it "not make sense"? Is there perhaps another way to count the number of records grouped by the value of a specific field?

Answer (score 0):

"all field are indexed" -- This is usually a bad sign.  Read about "composite" indexes.

The first query can be rewritten as

```
select  c.name,
        st_asgeojson(c.geom) AS 'geometry',
        ( SELECT count(*) FROM artifact
             WHERE county = c.id ) AS  tot
    from  county c;
```

That may run faster and avoid the memory problem.  Try it.

Here's another way:

```
SELECT  c.name,
        st_asgeojson(c.geom) AS 'geometry',
        a.tot
     FROM ( SELECT county, COUNT(*) AS tot
              FROM artifact
              GROUP BY county ) AS a
     JOIN county AS c  ON a.county = c.id;
```

That will probably do the grouping and grouping before walking through the geometry.

Comment: Thanx a lot for your answer, I noticed a slightly faster response, but not much difference. Why , in your experience, a nested query is better than a "with" construct?

Comment: @GiuseppeNaponiello - MySQL adds new features (`WITH` and Json) from time to time, but it usually takes more time to Optimize them.  `ALTER TABLE` is an extreme case:  2 decades.